# fflush alternative

Tags: c, string, generics

I did the mistake of using fflush(stdin) to flush the remainings of the stdin stream like that:

```
printf("Gimme number");
scanf("%d",&number);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Gimme string");
gets(string);
```

Of course I have included the header files and the rest.. I know that fflush is for stdout and NOT for stdin, but I badly need an alternative in order to use a gets after a scanf. I searched in old posts here but I only saw a suggestion about scanf("%c\n",c); . This drives the program to a nice crash when I do scanf("%d\n",x); Any ideas please?

Comment: Try `scanf("%d ",number);` (yes, include the space). Don't use `gets`, try `fgets` for a spin.

Comment: Or even `scanf("%d", &number);` ?

Comment: *Never* use `gets()`. It is inherently unsafe, so much so that it's been removed from the latest version of the C standard (the only function that's ever suffered such a fate).

Comment: fgets would be fgets(string, 15, stdin); ???

Comment: what if I don't know how many characters will the user type so that I enter the size??

Comment: scanf("%d ",&number); and scanf("%d", &number); don't work!!!!

Comment: Show us how `number` is declared?  `int number;` ??  `int* number;` ?? `float number;` ??  If you don't show us, we can't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to consume the newline left by the `scanf` via using something like `getchar()`:

```
printf("Gimme number");
scanf("%d",&number);
getchar();
printf("Gimme string");
gets(string);
```

Another possibility is to just use scanf's:

```
printf("Gimme number");
scanf("%d",&number);
printf("Gimme string");
scanf(" %99s", string);
```

Where you'd replace the `99` by whatever length your string buffer is, note the space before the `%` to make sure it ignores white space (or tabs or newlines) left on `stdin`.

Comment: I did put &number in my code!! It was a typo here.. I am sorry!!

Comment: @alex777 - NP, updated my code to match. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The `%s` conversion skips leading white space by itself, you don't need a space there. "Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a [, c, or n specifier."

Answer (score 0):

Read full lines from the input (lines containing the ENTER).
The parse the lines (possibly with `strtol()`, `srttod()`, or `sscanf()`).

```
char buffer[1000];
int number;
printf("Gimme number: ");
fflush(stdout);
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin); // needs error checking
number = strtol(buffer, &err, 10); // needs error checking
printf("Gimme string: ");
fflush(stdout);
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin); // needs error checking
strcpy(string, buffer);
string[strlen(string) - 1] = 0; // remove ENTER
```